# Are Temple Run 2 Christmas Artifacts still available after the holiday season?

Tags: temple-run-2

Level 9 includes an Objective called "all the rings".  Within this objective there are ten Christmas rings which must be collected.  Are Christmas artifacts only available during the Christmas holiday season? If so, now that we are in March 2014, how can we proceed beyond Level 9 without having collected them all?

Dr.Thomas

Comment: they should be available until you update it

Answer (score 1):

The Christmas artifacts are not rings, they are various Christmas-related items (sprig of holly, etc.)  I don't think those Christmas artifacts are available in the game anymore as I haven't seen them in a while.  They had Valentine's artifacts for a while as well.  But neither of those aren't needed to complete the "all the rings" objective and the ring artifacts are definitely still available as of the current (post-Valentine artifact) update.

So for completing the "all the rings" objective, it's actually good that the Christmas and Valentine artifacts aren't around anymore, as more of the artifacts you get from the chest are going to be rings.  If your experience is like mine, you will get many copies of some of the rings before you finally get whatever last missing one you need to complete the objective.

Comment: The 5 Christmas items were: candy cane, stocking, holly, present, and wreath.  Getting at least one of all 5 unlocked the ability to have any character wear a Santa hat but that wasn't an objective and wouldn't help get to level 10.  The Santa hat looks pretty silly on the characters that are already wearing a hat (Montoya, Smith.)

Answer (score 0):

The Christmas artifacts aren't rings. You have no need for them to pass Level 9. However there is a way to keep the Christmas artifacts. Don't update your device at all, and keep it off WiFi with the app open. It's difficult, but it works. I still have fourth of July artifacts.